# Use of IN, INNER JOIN and EXIST for a SELECT in 3 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select, inner-join

I'll try to make this simple.

I'm new to SQL and I have a situation where I need to provide 3 SELECT statement doing the same thing, one with IN, an other with INNER JOIN, and the last one with EXISTS. Normally I would be able to figure out how to do it, but it's the request that bothers me because I have to jump from one table to the other without the same "link" between them.

So let's say I have these 3 tables with their attributes :

```
[Channel] name_channel, URL_channel, company_channel
[Schedule_Channel] name_channel, num_movie, starting_date
[Movie] num_movie, name_movie
```

The request is to show the name, URL and company of every Channel that aired the movie 'Dracula' after november 1st 2015.

My question is, how do I jump from the table 'Channel' to 'Schedule_Channel' and then to 'Movie' so I can get both the starting_date and the movie name. I know I can use the "link" 'name_channel' between 'Channel' and 'Schedule' and the "link" 'num_movie' between 'Schedule' and 'Movie', I simply don't know how to write it down as IN, INNER JOIN and EXIST requests.

Phew, I hope my question is clear. Here is what I would do, based on what I could understand about those requests:

For the IN :

```
SELECT name_channel, URL_channel, company_channel
FROM Channel
WHERE name_channel IN (SELECT name_channel from Schedule_Channel WHERE starting_date > to_date('20151101 00:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS'))
AND name_channel IN (SELECT name_channel FROM Schedule_Channel WHERE num_movie IN (SELECT num_movie FROM Movie WHERE name_movie = 'Dracula'));
```

For the INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT c.name_channel, c.company_channel, c.URL_channel
FROM Channel c
INNER JOIN Schedule_Channel s
ON c.name_channel = s.name_channel
INNER JOIN Movie m
ON s.num_movie = s.num_movie WHERE s.starting_date > to_date('20151101 00:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') AND m.name_movie = 'Dracula';
```

And I have no idea how to do it for the EXIST...

I hope I asked this question the right way. Sorry if it's not the case.

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help me understand all this, it's a mess in my head :)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand this correctly you need write same query using EXISTS

should be smth like this:

```
SELECT c.name_channel, c.company_channel, c.URL_channel
FROM Channel c
  where EXISTS (
select * from Schedule_Channel s where s.name_channel = c.name_channel
    and s.starting_date > to_date('20151101 00:00:00','YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') 
    and EXISTS (select * from Movie m
      where m.num_movie = s.num_movie
        and m.name_movie = 'Dracula'
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
proc sql;
  select a.* from channel a,schedule_channel b, movie c
  where a.name_channel=b.name_channel and b.num_movie=c.num_movie
  and b.starting_date>to_date('2015-11-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
  and c.name_movie='Dracula'
```